# How can i make movies from the 'movies' dataset with multiple genres only have 1 single genre?

Tags: r, plot

I am making a diagram with R and i want to make a diagram showing movie budgets for different genres.

My problem is that most movies have more than one genre, for example (Drama, Comdey) or (Drama,Adventure, Sci-Fi):
[image: plot]

How can i make movies have only one genre?, like (Drama), (Adventure), (Horror), (Western),...
for example movie with genre(Drama, Comdey) and movie with genre (Drama,Adventure, Sci-Fi) will be added to genre (Drama)

Comment: If you just want to keep the first genre you could use `grepl` or `tidyverse::separate` for example: `separate(df1, col = what, into = "what2", sep = ",", extra = "drop")` where `df1` is the data frame, `col = what`: `what` is the name of the column you want to modify, `into = "what2"`: `what2` is the name of the new column. This will drop the original column, if you want to keep the original column, add `remove = F`.